# HTML & CSS size monitors

Tags: css, html

I was wondering on how you make HTML & CSS work on different size monitors. at the moment I've made a web page on my PC however, when I load it on my laptop all the text is overlapping and the position has changed. Is there a way to stop this?

Comment: This called responsive web design where everything sized and positioned by the viewport of browser on devices. Follow [Responsive Web Design Tutorial](https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_rwd_intro.asp)

Comment: You can use css framework for your projects for achieving responsive design. Ex. Bootstrap or Fountain css framework.

Answer (score 2):

You need to write @media css query for diff size:

```
example:
 @media screen and (min-width: 480px) {
   .column {
     width: 50%;
    }
 }
```

etc....

Answer (score 0):

Also, use this meta tag:

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
```

Comment: Where about would you put this in the code?

Comment: Right under <head> in your HTML.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use media Media Queries here you have an example.
You can see the W3schools documentation about [Responsive Web Design - Media Queries](https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_rwd_mediaqueries.asp)
I hope this example works for you.

```css
body {
  background-color: lightgreen;
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 600px) {
  body {
    background-color: red;
  }
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
</head>
<body>
<p>Resize the browser window. When the width of this document is 600 pixels or less, the background-color is "red", otherwise it is "lightgreen".</p>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

The above answers are great, I would also add to learn responsive design in its essence and not to simply throw media queries everywhere in your code when something breaks.

Learning about Grid-View, for example, is a very good place to start as sing a grid-view is very helpful when designing web pages. It makes it easier to place elements on the page.

Here's a simple demo where the columns will re-arrange depending on the screen size: On a big screen it might look better with the content organized in three columns, but on a small screen it would be better if the content items were stacked on top of each other.

The classes above `col-s1` to col-s10 can be combined to create more dynamic and flexible layouts.

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.row::after {
  content: "";
  clear: both;
  display: table;
}

[class*="col-"] {
  float: left;
  padding: 15px;
}

html {
  font-family: "Lucida Sans", sans-serif;
}

.header {
  background-color: #9933cc;
  color: #ffffff;
  padding: 15px;
}

.menu ul {
  list-style-type: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.menu li {
  padding: 8px;
  margin-bottom: 7px;
  background-color: #33b5e5;
  color: #ffffff;
  box-shadow: 0 1px 3px rgba(0,0,0,0.12), 0 1px 2px rgba(0,0,0,0.24);
}

.menu li:hover {
  background-color: #0099cc;
}

.aside {
  background-color: #33b5e5;
  padding: 15px;
  color: #ffffff;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 14px;
  box-shadow: 0 1px 3px rgba(0,0,0,0.12), 0 1px 2px rgba(0,0,0,0.24);
}

.footer {
  background-color: #0099cc;
  color: #ffffff;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 12px;
  padding: 15px;
}

/* For mobile phones: */
[class*="col-"] {
  width: 100%;
}

@media only screen and (min-width: 600px) {
  /* For tablets: */
  .col-s-1 {width: 8.33%;}
  .col-s-2 {width: 16.66%;}
  .col-s-3 {width: 25%;}
  .col-s-4 {width: 33.33%;}
  .col-s-5 {width: 41.66%;}
  .col-s-6 {width: 50%;}
  .col-s-7 {width: 58.33%;}
  .col-s-8 {width: 66.66%;}
  .col-s-9 {width: 75%;}
  .col-s-10 {width: 83.33%;}
  .col-s-11 {width: 91.66%;}
  .col-s-12 {width: 100%;}
}
@media only screen and (min-width: 768px) {
  /* For desktop: */
  .col-1 {width: 8.33%;}
  .col-2 {width: 16.66%;}
  .col-3 {width: 25%;}
  .col-4 {width: 33.33%;}
  .col-5 {width: 41.66%;}
  .col-6 {width: 50%;}
  .col-7 {width: 58.33%;}
  .col-8 {width: 66.66%;}
  .col-9 {width: 75%;}
  .col-10 {width: 83.33%;}
  .col-11 {width: 91.66%;}
  .col-12 {width: 100%;}
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
</head>
<body>
<div class="header">
  <h1>Chania</h1>
</div>

<div class="row">
  <div class="col-3 col-s-3 menu">
    <ul>
      <li>The Flight</li>
      <li>The City</li>
      <li>The Island</li>
      <li>The Food</li>
    </ul>
  </div>

  <div class="col-6 col-s-9">
    <h1>The City</h1>
    <p>Chania is the capital of the Chania region on the island of Crete. The city can be divided in two parts, the old town and the modern city.</p>
  </div>

  <div class="col-3 col-s-12">
    <div class="aside">
      <h2>What?</h2>
      <p>Chania is a city on the island of Crete.</p>
      <h2>Where?</h2>
      <p>Crete is a Greek island in the Mediterranean Sea.</p>
      <h2>How?</h2>
      <p>You can reach Chania airport from all over Europe.</p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="footer">
  <p>Resize the browser window to see how the content respond to the resizing.</p>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```